# String to Date PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have table name bill_date 
and this is my table row, the field type of create_date is character varying

```
id | create_date 
1  | 20080108
2  | 20080116
```

I want to convert create_date to Date but when I used this QUERY

```
SELECT to_date(create_date, 'YYYYddmm'),* FROM bill_date
```

I got wrong result

```
2008-08-01
2009-04-03
```

there something wrong in field type? any help. thanks

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: I suppose you would like the output to be `2008-01-08`? Can I suggest you leave it in the format given to you by `to_date`, as this is ISO format?

Comment: I suppose you would like the output to be 2008-01-08? yes, and row 2 also wrong output.

Comment: have you tried `select '20080108'::date`

Comment: The output of `2008-08-01` for the format `YYYYddmm` absolutely correct for the input value `20080108`. 2008 = YYYY, 01 = dd, 08 = mm. If you want the input value to be parsed differently you need to use a different format mask, e.g. `yyyymmdd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT '20080108'::DATE
    ,to_date('20080108', 'YYYYddmm')
```

result

```
date         to_date    
----------   ---------- 
2008-01-08   2008-08-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <columnname> TYPE DATE using to_date(<columnname>,'YYYYDDMM');
```